# Remote Desktop Connection Randomly Stopped Connecting to Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Tags: windows-7, remote-access, dynamic-dns

I have allowed remote desktop connections on my home machine:

- Windows 7 x64 Ultimate.
- Fixed IPV4 set via LAN (in network adapter settings).
- Router is set to forward port 3389 to my fixed IP (192.168.1.10).
- DHCP on the router is set from 192.168.1.11 - 192.168.1.50.
- I have a free dyndns.org account that was working fine for a couple of months.
- RDC is allowed in the Windows Firewall settings (I only have Windows firewall and MS Security Essentials running, the router's firewall is turned off).
- RDC services all appear to be started.

This was working for months up until the end of last year, 2011. I tried to connect in to my home machine from work this week and I keep getting the following message:

> Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these
>   reasons: 1) Remote access to the server is not enabled 2) The remote
>   computer is turned off 3) The remote computer is not available on the
>   network Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to
>   the network, and that remote access is enabled.

Remote desktop is enabled, the IP is static, my RDC listening port is 3389 and it is forwarded from the router but I cannot connect anymore. I have even dropped the who can connect setting to:

> Allowing connections from computers runnning any version of Windows
>   (less secure)

from

> Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with
>   Network Level Authentication (more secure)

I can ping *.dyndns.org from work and I am getting a valid IP.

If anyone has any suggestions I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**

I do not appear to be able to ping *.dyndns.org from a remote location (where * is my account).